# Error Message Migrating Wordpress Website with MigrateGuru - Fix Possible?

Tags: wordpress, mysql, hostgator

Hi I have a quick question... I am trying to migrate my Wordpress site from SiteGround to HostGator. I am using the plugin MigrateGuru to simplify things. At the end of the migrate process I get the error message:

> Error while creating the table wpb7_wpns_malware_hash_file. The key
> was too long, MAX key length is 767 bytes.

Apparently HostGator only uses MySQL version 5.6.x and thus can't support prefix lengths greater than 767 bytes in InnoDB tables (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)). Is there an easy fix to this problem? I have a background in comp sci and coincidentally am reading a book right now on Database Processing so I have a general idea of what's going on.
Thanks!

Comment: Using Hostgator is a mistake in the first place. That table is not a vital WP database table.  Export a backup of the database and then delete that table, then try migrating.  But when the Malware plugin tries to recreate the table, you are likely to have problems as the table key will still be too long.